# A vue.js project with Parcel ,but there are errors in css file when using images files

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, parcel

This is my project: [github](https://github.com/DaXiong1/vue_open_parcel).

In app.js:

```
import '../static/css/common.css'
```

I imported 'common.css', then executed the command 'npm run build'(parcel build index.html), that is the result:

[[image: enter image description here]]

But if I removed some code from the bottom of common.css like this:

[[image: common.css]]

Then execute 'npm run build', there is no error, excuted successfully...

So I don't know how to import images in css with Parcel.I can't find solutions on Parcel official website.

Please help me,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this :

```
if(!this.bundleLoaders){
    this.bundleLoaders = new Set();
}
this.bundleLoaders.add(mod.type);
```

Here -> 
`\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\packagers\JSPackager.js on line 56`

Comment: I've added your code, it works and there is no error when execute 'npm run build/start'.So I imported 4 css files in app.js, but they don't work.I find this（<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/72c1dc2c47bb67ee19d8674496966a6f.css">）in Dom,but it seems not work.You can see the latest code on my github.